# i am getting the null values ,whenever i am using `MPMediaItemCollection` convert `MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL` to data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mpmediaitem

i am getting the null values ,whenever i am using `MPMediaItemCollection` convert `MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL` to data?

here my code

```
MPMediaItemCollection *collection=[allAlbumsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
MPMediaItem *item = [collection representativeItem];

NSLog(@" songs titles_str url is===>%@",[item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL]);

NSLog(@"class type is %@",[[item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL] class]);

self.songData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL]];

NSLog(@"original data is %@",self.songData);
```

here i am getting url for song `ipod-library://item/item.mp3?id=-9207595762773025867`

but when i convert into data i getting null value 
Thanks for advance.

Comment: where you are initializing AudioFile?

Comment: what is your output of `NSLog();`, show us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the URL has a custom scheme, `ipod-library`, which can only be used with `AVFoundation` methods, for example `AVAsset` objects.

The [MPMediaItem Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaItem_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) says this about `MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL`:

> MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL
>
> A URL pointing to the media item, from which an AVAsset object (or other URL-based AV Foundation
>    object) can be created, with any options as desired. Value is an NSURL object.
>
> The URL has the custom scheme of ipod-library. For example, a URL might look like this:
>
> ipod-library://item/item.m4a?id=12345
>
> **Usage of the URL outside of the AV Foundation framework is not supported.**

Comment: can you please provide some instructions to get data here i am using NSURL *url = [item valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
    
    AVURLAsset *songAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL: url options:nil];
    
    AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset: songAsset
                                                                      presetName: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough];

Comment: @Pandu1251 Sorry, not sure how you'd access the raw data from the `AVAsset`.

Comment: ok can you know any way to get the file to data here AVURLAsset *songAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL: url options:nil];
    
    NSLog(@"url is %@",songAsset);url is <AVURLAsset: 0x1ac860, URL = ipod-library://item/item.mp3?id=-9207595762773025867>

Comment: A quick Google suggests you want to use `AVAssetReader` to get the `outputs` and then use `AVAssetReaderOutput`s `copyNextSampleBuffer` method.